# Проблема с asyncio в телеграм боте на aiogram (python)

Tags: python, многопоточность, aiogram, asyncio, асинхронность

Пишу телеграм бота на библиотеке aiogram, и мои команды запускают долгие парсеры сайтов. Проблема в том, что когда один человек запустил такой парсер, у всех остальных перестает работать бот. Решил проблему использованием библиотеки **threading**, и создания процессов. Вот моя функция:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def function(message: types.Message):
    threads = []
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM database')
    users = cursor.fetchall()
    for n in users:
        keyword = 'instagram'
        user_id = message.chat.id
        t = Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(send_news(keyword,user_id), ))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Вот также главная функция send_news, к которой идет запрос:

```py
async def send_news(keyword, user_id):
    news = parsers.parse_search_google(keyword)
    await bot.send_message(user_id, 'YES')
```

Вот как работает парсер (если это нужно):

```py
def check_url(url_feed): 
    """функция получает линк на рсс ленту, возвращает распаршенную ленту с помощью feedpaeser"""
    return feedparser.parse(url_feed)

def getHeadlines(url_feed):
    """функция для получения заголовков новости"""
    headlines = []
    lenta = check_url (url_feed)
    for item_of_news in lenta['items']:
        if len(headlines) <= 9:
            headlines.append(item_of_news ['title'])
    return headlines

def getLinks(url_feed):
    """функция для получения ссылки на источник новости"""
    links = []
    lenta = check_url(url_feed)
    for item_of_news in lenta['items']:
        links.append(item_of_news ['link'])
    return links
def parse_search_google(keyword):
    URL = f'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={keyword}&hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru'
    headlines = getHeadlines(URL)
    link = getLinks(URL)
    return headlines, link
```

**Но проблема в том, как отправить сообщение пользователю из функции send_news?** Я не силен в асинхронности. Я сделал функцию через asynco, а ее запуск через asyncio, и по идее это должно было решить проблему, но я получаю длинную ошибку:

> RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-10' coro=<send_news() running at D:\7on\NewsletterBot\V1\bot.py:681> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\Users\ddeme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending cb=[shield.._outer_done_callback() at C:\Users\ddeme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:907]> attached to a different loop
> Future exception was never retrieved
> future: <Future finished exception=ServerDisconnectedError('Server disconnected')>
> aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected`

Comment: Бот собирает результаты найденные в google news?

Comment: сокеты через процессы передать не реальная задача для новичка, но так как у вас асинкио, то и треды не нужны. сделайте обычные таски

Comment: @ProgerOffline Бот собирает данные с многих ресурсов, конкретно в этом случае с сайта google news

Comment: @eri С обычными тасками тоже работать не приходилось, вы можете показать пример кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перехода к обычным таскам вот это:

```
threads = []
...
for n in users:
    ...
    t = Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(send_news(keyword,user_id), ))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

можно упростить таким образом:

```
tasks = []
...
for n in users:
    ...
    t = asyncio.create_task(send_news(keyword,user_id))
    tasks.append(t)

for t in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
    await t
```

Но тут всё стопариться будет на `feedparser` - тут нужно поставить aiohttp перед ним

```
import aiohttp

async def send_news(keyword, user_id):
    news = await parsers.parse_search_google(keyword)
    await bot.send_message(user_id, 'YES')

async def check_url(keyword, session): 
    ...
    async with session.get(
               "https://news.google.com/rss/search",
               params={'q':keyword, 'ceid':'RU:ru' ...}) as r:
        data_feed = await r.text()
    return feedparser.parse(data_feed)


def getHeadlines(lenta):
    ...

def getLinks(lenta):
    ...


async def parse_search_google(keyword):
    ...
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    lenta = await check_url(keyword, session)
    await session.close()
    headlines = getHeadlines(lenta)
    link = getLinks(lenta)
    
    ...
```

Попутно исправил двойной заход в check_url с одной и той же ссылкой.